# Why does file_get_contents() Javascript Output not Execute?

Tags: php, javascript, widget, sendgrid

**Backstory:** I'm trying to use the Newsletter Widget from SendGrid but they currently don't offer it using SSL. So any requests to https:// just redirect to http:// and then browsers complain about insecure content on my secure site.

Ok fine, so I implement something like this in PHP:

```
$output = file_get_contents('http://sendgrid.com/newsletter/getSubscriptionWidget?p=xxx');
```

And then in my view have this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo($output); ?>
 </script>
```

Viewing the source of this page after execution shows that it pulls the javascript widget code in just fine. **BUT**, it doesn't work. By "not working" I mean the javascript code never executes.

If I load it (in a non-https development environment) using the script tag like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sendgrid.com/newsletter/getSubscriptionWidget?p=xxx">
```

Then it works just fine!

**TL;DR;** What would cause javascript to execute fine when loaded under the *src* attribute of the **script** element and not work when echoed as content inside **script** tags?

P.S. You can view the SendGrid widget source [here](https://sendgrid.com/newsletter/getSubscriptionWidget?p=OtNr1mIHXsJXZw2xPz9OVZ3eIrrePAJ0RkYisa8L6mZWdToH6Z3dKB0j0N8fOf1g).

Comment: Look at the generated source of your page

Comment: I did. This is what it comes out as: http://pastebin.com/PKXwf002 You can see that the Javascript shows up between the **<script>** tags. Problem is it never executes. Does it have to do with the fact that it's wrapped in parenthesis?

Comment: Great question. I've had a similar issue and I had to nest the code in window.onload / document.ready. No idea if this is the case here, but thought it might help generate some ideas.

Comment: I've tried nesting it in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`...didn't help.

Comment: Any web console output/errors when loading the page?

Comment: No, but I finally figured it out...posting below as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Turns out the SendGrid code checks to ensure the script tag is pointing at the script using this:

```
// replace each instance
$('script').each(function (wIdx, wElem) {
var tag, src, table, trSubmit, tdSubmit, form, emailInput, message, params;

tag = $(this);
src = tag.attr('src');
params = RegExp('p=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(src);
// check if corret script
if ($.isArray(params) && params.length > 1 && key === params[1]) {
  form = $('<form />', {
    'class': 'SG_widget_form',
    'method': 'POST',
    'action': postURL,
    'accept-charset': 'UTF-8'
  });
  form.insertBefore(tag);
  tag.remove();
  message = $('<span />').insertBefore(form).hide();
```

... there is more after that, but that is the important piece. By adding the **src** attribute to the tag and pointing it at the correct location, the browser will block loading it normally, but will then execute the code I echoed with PHP inside of it.

Probably fairly specific to my problem, but hopefully it will help someone else.